# How could send a label inside a panel as a DynamicContextKey?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

```
    <tr class="content" id="row1" onmouseover="$find('pce_1').showPopup();" onmouseout="$find('pce_1').hidePopup();">
<td class="style28">
    &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style30">
            <asp:Panel ID="panel_player_1" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
        </td>
        <td class="style21" align="right">
            <asp:Panel ID="panel_table_1" runat="server" Width="50px">
            <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel222" TargetControlID="panel_table_1"
               DynamicContextKey='<%# Eval("panel_table_1") %>' BehaviorID="pce_1"
               DynamicControlID="Panel222"
               DynamicServiceMethod="GetDynamicContent" Position="Bottom" OffsetX="-485" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </td>

</tr>
```

i have ten blocks like this...and i put a label inside the panel_table_1 and panel_player_1 by codebehind...i want to send the text o label inside the panel_table_1 as DynamicContextKey.how should i do this?

Comment: is there any one can guide me?

Comment: this is the solution : http://forums.asp.net/t/1864828.aspx/1?How+could+send+a+label+inside+a+panel+as+a+DynamicContextKey+